# AngularJS + PhantomJS for Crawling

Tags: ajax, angularjs, nginx, seo, phantomjs

I either do not quite get how I can have Google or any Social Network to use Phantomjs to render my site or I have did something wrong.

I am using Nginx, Angularjs with Html5Mode Urls and Phantomjs.
Furthermore I use steeve/angular-seo to handle the phantomjs stuff. For this I have included the angular-seo.js and added

```
$scope.htmlReady();
```

To the end of every controller.

My Nginx config for my domain dev.example.com includes this at the end of the server tag.

```
if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_=(.*)") {
        rewrite ^ /snapshot${uri};
    }   

    location /snapshot {
        proxy_pass http://dev.example.com:8888;
        proxy_connect_timeout  60s;
    }
```

My index.html includes this meta tag to let google see that it is an AJAX site.

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!" />
```

Then I run

```
phantomjs --disk-cache=no angular-seo-server.js 8888 http://dev.example.com
```

in the server console.
Now I tried to visit my site manually with http://dev.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/
but the site that I get back is not correctly displayed and the snapshot is also not saved to the snapshot folder.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but this is a good resource on Angularjs and Phantomjs: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/serious-angular-seo.html